# How to Insert code after fork on PhusionPassenger.on_event()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there a parameter for PhusionPassenger.on_event that will act for  after_fork? instead of :starting_worker_process

I would like to monkey patch  class and method of rails controllers and models that run in passenger. The problem is that the rails will reloads if the rails noticed an updates in class or controller and model while the passenger creates new process that gives me a hard time since the monkey patched classes where reset to original.

Is there a way how to do it?

Here is my sample code;

```
if defined?(PhusionPassenger)
  PhusionPassenger.on_event(:starting_worker_process) do |forked|
     require 'path/monkeypatched_script'
  end
end
```

Inside the monkeypatched_script is my script where I tried to monkey patch a class and method.

When I run my application it generates 3 processes. The first 2 process the 
**require 'path/monkeypatched_script'**  perform well however in the 3rd process the **require 'path/monkeypatched_script'** didn't perform.

back for my question if there's another parameter aside from :starting_worker_process that will act for after_fork.

Here is the script of the monkey patch;

```
Article.class_eval do 
  alias :reduce_str_without_apm :reduce_str 
  def reduce_str(*args, &block) 
    return reduce_str_without_apm(*args, &block) unless RubyAPM.current_transaction

    name = "Custom Instrument" 
    type = "Article#reduce_str" 
    ctx = Span::Context.new( CATEGORY: 'Ruby' ) 

    req = reduce_str_without_apm(*args, &block) 

    RubyAPM.span name, type, context: ctx do 
      req 
    end 
  end 
end
```

The purpose is to fetch the data, monitor the class/method performance and add it to logs

Comment: Where is your monkey patch code? Can you give an example of code you have tried? see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello I had edited and do my best to explained more detail.

Comment: It's still unclear what your monkey patch is even doing or why you need it. But this design pattern seems flawed. Where and what is the code which handles the forking?

Comment: also what mode are you using? standalone, apache, or nginx?

Comment: the mode I used is standalone. I monkey patched a method from a controller/models, for example, adding few string displays. I don't have yet a code the will handles the forking since what I currently have is a code the monkey-patch method that belongs to a controller/model.  What I  don't know is which portion of the on_event or is there another parameter I mentioned above and where to put the fork code

Comment: We're shooting in the dark here. You have not explained WHY you think you need this monkey patch.  What is the purpose of this? Without seeing the patch script, we just can't be of any further help.

Comment: @lacostenycoder the monkeypatch script. 

`Article.class_eval do
  alias :reduce_str_without_apm :reduce_str
  def #{current_method}(*args, &block)
    return reduce_str_without_apm(*args, &block) unless RubyAPM.current_transaction
    name = "Custom Instrument"
    type = "Article#reduce_str"
    ctx = Span::Context.new(
              CATEGORY: 'Ruby'
            )
    req = reduce_str_without_apm(*args, &block)
    RubyAPM.span name, type, context: ctx do
      req
    end
  end
end`
The purpose is to fetch the data, monitor the class/method performance and add it to logs

Comment: Please update your question with the code you added in the previous comment.